# Java: what is the best way to convert ArrayList<Byte> to byte[]?

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
try {
    int data = putObjectRequest.getInputStream().read();
    bytes.add((byte) data);
    while (data != -1) {
        data = putObjectRequest.getInputStream().read();
        bytes.add((byte)data);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to convert this to `byte[]`.
is this this the only way?

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[bytes.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
   byteArray[i] = bytes.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of an `ArrayList<Byte>` to collect your input:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    int data = putObjectRequest.getInputStream().read();
    while (data != -1) {
        bos.write(data);
        data = putObjectRequest.getInputStream().read();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

This avoids the horrible overhead of boxing and unboxing every byte. (I also fixed a small bug in your original code where you would write `-1` if `putObjectRequest` was empty.)

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[bytes.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
   byteArray[i] = bytes.get(i);
}
```

Yes, this is the only way.

```
byte[] byteArray = bytes.toArray(new byte[bytes.size()]);
```

Using `toArray()` as proposed in another answer does **not** work because the method can't automatically convert the wrapper type `Byte` to the primitive `byte`.

Comment: With an ArrayList implementation this is fine but it will run in polynomial time on any linked list implementation. Writing to object array and then iterating through with static casts is safer because guarantees linear time.

Comment: @SamGrondahl - OP is using `ArrayList`, which is not a linked list implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) in Apache Commons:

```
byte[] byteArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(bytes.toArray(new Byte[bytes.size()]));
```

Comment: Which uses the code in main-- answer, I'll bet.  You'll have to decide whether you prefer three lines of code or one line of code and a JAR dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Easier:

```
Byte[] byteArray = bytes.toArray(new Byte[bytes.size()]);
```

And if you really want primitives:

```
byte[] primitives = new byte[byteArray.length]
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
  primitives [i] = (byte)byteArray[i];
}
```

This guarantees you linear time complexity for both linked list and resizing array implementations.

It's been supported since 5.0:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: true, this doesn't even compiles

Comment: The OP wants a `byte[]`, not a `Byte[]`... I guess?

Comment: Yes, I wanted `byte[]` not `Byte[]` as mentioned in OP

Comment: it is not necessary to pass array size as an argument.

Comment: So instead of simply iterating over the original `ArrayList<Byte>` as OP is doing, you propose converting the `ArrayList<Byte>` to a `Byte[]` and then iterating. How is this an improvement? (OP is using `ArrayList`, not some random linked list implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use something like [`TByteList`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/TByteList.html) from [`trove4j`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net), instead of your `ArrayList<Byte>`. Your algorithm would then become:

```
TByteList bytes = new TByteArrayList();
try {
    int data = putObjectRequest.getInputStream().read();
    bytes.add((byte) data);
    while (data != -1) {
        data = putObjectRequest.getInputStream().read();
        bytes.add((byte)data);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] byteArray = bytes.toArray();
```

Comment: This won't quite work, since `TByteList` is an interface. It would need to be `TByteList bytes = new TByteArrayList();`. Then it wouldn't be much different from using the core `ByteArrayOutputStream` class (which would avoid a jar dependency).

Comment: @TedHopp: Whoops thanks for the interface hint. You're right, using `BAOS` is probably optimal in this case. I was kind of throwing this in as an option to the OP's question *"is this this the only way?"*